# Как получить отклик, если хотя бы один из CheckBox в QGroupBox поменяет свое состояние (PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Пишу для себя приложение с помощью PyQt5.

В приложении содержится нескольких (около 10) чекбоксов. Подумала, что разумным будет объединить эти чекбоксы в QGroupBox.

Можно ли получать событие, привязанное именно к QGroupBox, если один из чекбоксов поменяет свое состояние, не прописывая при этом `self.ui.checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.my_method)` для каждого чекбокса?

Comment: в цикле пройдитесь по всем checkbox внутри QGroupBox и задайте им stateChanged.connect(self.my_method)

Comment: большое спасибо! я думаю, в итоге так и сделаю, но очень интересно узнать, нет ли для QGroupBox подходящего метода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [QButtonGroup](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) для логического объединения кнопок.

У [QButtonGroup](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) есть удобные сигналы, например [buttonClicked](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked) для отлова взаимодействия с кнопкой.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QGroupBox, QCheckBox, QButtonGroup, QGridLayout


def _on_button_clicked(button: QCheckBox):
    print(button, button.text(), button.isChecked())


app = QApplication([])

button_group = QButtonGroup()
button_group.setExclusive(False)
button_group.buttonClicked.connect(_on_button_clicked)

buttons_array = [
    [QCheckBox('a1'), QCheckBox('a2'), QCheckBox('a3')],
    [QCheckBox('b1'), QCheckBox('b2'), QCheckBox('b3')],
    [QCheckBox('c1'), QCheckBox('c2'), QCheckBox('c3')],
]

main_layout = QGridLayout()

for i, row in enumerate(buttons_array):
    for j, button in enumerate(row):
        button_group.addButton(button)
        main_layout.addWidget(button, i, j)

mw = QGroupBox()
mw.setLayout(main_layout)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: спасибо большое! этот способ сработал!

Answer (score 1):

Если у `QGroupBox` есть те кнопки, то они являются его детьми.

Чтобы найти детей используем метод `findChildren`. в который мы передадим способ поиска – по типу `QCheckBox`.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QGroupBox, QCheckBox, QGridLayout, QObject


def _on_button_clicked(checked: bool):
    # Небольшой костыль для получения объекта, который отправил сигнал
    # Костыль не нужен будет если метод будет внутри виджета -- button = self.sender()
    button = QObject().sender()
    print(button, button.text(), button.isChecked(), checked)


app = QApplication([])

buttons_array = [
    [QCheckBox('a1'), QCheckBox('a2'), QCheckBox('a3')],
    [QCheckBox('b1'), QCheckBox('b2'), QCheckBox('b3')],
    [QCheckBox('c1'), QCheckBox('c2'), QCheckBox('c3')],
]

main_layout = QGridLayout()

for i, row in enumerate(buttons_array):
    for j, button in enumerate(row):
        main_layout.addWidget(button, i, j)

mw = QGroupBox()
mw.setLayout(main_layout)

# Ищем у QGroupBox наши кнопки, чтобы им указать сигнал
for button in mw.findChildren(QCheckBox):
    button.clicked.connect(_on_button_clicked)

mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Нет разницы между "подходящим методом" в QGroupBox и перебором всех checkbox внутри него. Реализация такого "подходящего метода" была бы перебором всех checkbox внутри него. Грубо говоря [QGroupBox](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgroupbox.html) всего лишь класс который может быть унаследован или переписан.. Все его методы есть в документации

Comment: не смотрела с такой стороны, спасибо!